# JavaScript - Lexical scope, Closure and Google developer tool

Tags: javascript

Why does google developer tool show that closure is happening? when it's just lexical scope here.

Maybe I don't understand differences between closure and lexical scoping, as I know closure happens when outer function **returns** inner function, and in my example it's just lexical scoping because execution stack of first() function does not disappear and it's waiting for second() function to be executed and just after that disappear.

Here is code and screenshot of google developer tool.
Thanks in advance

```js
'use strict';

const myName = 'George';

function first() {
  const age = 25;
  function second() {
    const job = 'teacher';
    console.log(` name: ${myName}, age:${age}, job: ${job}`);
  }
  second();
}

first();
```

[image]

Comment: `second` *closes over* `age`. That's what a closure is.

Answer (score 2):

> ...as I know closure happens when outer function **returns** inner function...

That's incorrect. The closure is formed when the function is *created*. It doesn't matter whether you return it, retain it by other means, or (as in your example) not retain it at all.

`second` closes over the context of the call to `first`, which contains `age`. That closure doesn't *remain* once `first` returns, because nothing retains a reference to `second`, but it does get formed and exist briefly.

Comment: Then how does outer and inner functions has access to the global environment? Is that still by closure? thanks in advance

Comment: @Leonardo - Yup! All JavaScript functions are closures over the global environment. (Actually over at least two global environments, the "outer" global environment that the global object provides, and the "inner" global environment that holds new-style global `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations. [And on browsers, that outer global environment has multiple layers... :-) ])

Comment: @Leonardo - I should have said "directly or indirectly" in my comment above. A function created at global scope (like your `first`) closes over the global execution context. A function created within that function (like your `second`) closes over the execution context for the call to the outer function during which it's created; that context has a link to the outer context (the global context). So that inner function *indirectly* closes over the global context.

Comment: Sure, but what I meant was that global environment (In this case myName: "George" variable) is saved in Script instead of Closure(checkout my screenshot of google deceloper tool). What does this Script mean and why is myName variable there?

Comment: Your script code is executed at global scope, so `myName` is a global variable. There is no script scope. There is *module* scope, in modules. But non-module scripts execute at global scope.

Comment: When `second` uses `myName`, the JavaScript engine looks in the execution context for the call to `second` for a `myName` variable (or more generally, *binding*). Since it doesn't find one, it looks in the next outer context (the one for the call to`first`); since it doesn't find it there, either, it looks in the next outer one (global scope), and finds it there. (I'm glossing over details here, Bindings are held in something called a lexical environment which is associated with the execution context, but that's a detail.)